# CSS how to push text away from border

Tags: html, css

Basically I have this code for a container which holds widgets at the side of my side:

[image]

However as you can see the text is touching the border. Is there anyway to fix this? I am not too sure how to do this in CSS.

```
.widget {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-style:clear;
}
.widget h2 {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0 5px;
    font-weight:normal;
    border-bottom:1px solid #21a1e1;
}
.widget .inner {
    margin:0 10px;
    border-style:clear;
}

/* Aside */
aside {
    width:260px;
    float:right;
    border-top: 1px solid #21a1e1;
    border-left:1px solid #21a1e1;
    border-right: 1px solid #21a1e1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #21a1e1;
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Try setting the width of the `body` or the `Div` covering all the components.

Comment: why do you use `top-bottom-left-right` simplely write `border:1px solid 21a1e1;` this will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `aside` class is the class for the sidebar, you can just add a `margin-left: 20px;` (or whatever value you want) to the class definition:

```
aside {
    width: 260px;
    float: right;
    border-top: 1px solid #21a1e1;
    border-left: 1px solid #21a1e1;
    border-right: 1px solid #21a1e1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #21a1e1;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px; // Add here
}
```

The margin is outside of the border (see image below, it's from the Chrome Developer Tools. The blue is the content of the element, the padding is the inside space of the element, the yellow is the border and the margin is the outside space of the element. Notice that there is a black box around border, that's the edge of the element itself, the margin is additional space on the outside.

[image: el-padding-border-margin]